# Use \newcommand in \newenvironment - content of environment is argument of \newcommand

Tags: macros, environments

I want to create an environment, that generates a new command. There are some similar examples on google, but nothing fits exactly.

The minimal (not) working example shows best, what I want:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%Thats my environment:
\newenvironment{LHZZ}[1]{
\newcommand{\csname LH#1\endcsname }[1]\bgroup
}{\egroup}

%Thats the use of it. It is very important, that I can use arguments:  
\begin{LHZZ}{XY}
write stuff here 

refer to #1
\end{LHZZ}
```

The environment above should (but doesnt) equal the following:

```
% not part of the code !!!!!
\newcommand{\LHXY}[1]{
write stuff here

refer to #1
}
```

The following is the call in the document.

```
\begin{document}
\LHXY{parameter} %the command \LHXY has been created indirectly by \begin{LHZZ}
\end{document}
```

The output should be:

> write stuff here
>
> refer to parameter

It doesnt work. It says `\csname` is already defined. But I dont want to define `\csname`. It is just the first command inside the argument. What do I have to change, to make this work?

Edit: There is a purpose for this, what seems to be code golfing. This should lead into a package which can be used by people who are not Tex-safe. The package is for making brochures for marriages, church service, etc. easily.

Edit 2:
I sticked to one of the given solutions as far as possible and far as I understood it. Unfortunately, I need one optional parameter. To understand, what is the meaning of this quirky code, have a look at the example songbook and the call of it. The almost final version as a still not working MWE:

```
%Business as usual
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{environ}

%This sets a default value
\newcommand{\LHliederStandard}{n}

%This calls the environment(s)
\newcommand{\LHsong}[3][\LHliederStandard]{
\csname LH#2\endcsname[#1]#3 %indirect call of what is defined in Liederbuch environment
}

\makeatletter
%This is the Liederbuch environment (Liederbuch = songbook)
\NewEnviron{Liederbuch}[1]{
\xdef\LB@my@temp{
\noexpand\newcommand{\csname LH#1\endcsname}[2][\relax]{
\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}
}
}
\aftergroup\LB@my@temp
}
\makeatother

%This is the Lied environment (Lied = song)
\NewEnviron{Lied}[2]{
\ifnum\numexpr#2=\numexpr##3 %the double # refers to parameter of the level above, or doesnt it.
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{##2}=0
\BODY
\fi
\fi
}

%example for a songbook
\begin{Liederbuch}{songbook}

\begin{Lied}{n}{1}
song 1 mode n
\end{Lied}

\begin{Lied}{nt}{2}
song 2 mode nt
\end{Lied}

\end{Liederbuch}

%call of the songbook
\begin{document}

\LHsong{songbook}{1}     %calls song 1 mode n
\LHsong[nt]{songbook}{2} %calls song 2 mode nt
%hypothetical other songbook
\LHsong[n]{childrensongs}{35}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to `\expandafter` the `\newcommand` relative to the stuff which comes next. Not sure whether this works with `\newcommand`, though. But probably you want to look at the `environ` package.

Comment: This can't work this way -- you can't grab the environment content like this.

Comment: I used `\expandafter` in some tries, but it didn't work.

Comment: That's why I said you should look at `environ`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command form is easier:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\LHZZ}[2]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname LH#1\endcsname[1]{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\LHZZ{XY}{%
  write stuff here

  refer to #1%
}

\LHXY{parameter}

\end{document}
```

If you really insist in using an environment, use `environ`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{LHZZ}[1]{%
  \edef\maestroglanz@temp{%
    \unexpanded{\expandafter\gdef\csname LH#1\endcsname}####1{\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}%
  }%
  \maestroglanz@temp
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{LHZZ}{XY}
write stuff here

refer to #1
\end{LHZZ}

\LHXY{parameter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

An implementation using `xparse` and `expl3`; the largest part of the code is the definition of the error messages in case the environment is called twice with the same argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{LHZZ}[1]
 {
  \cs_set_protected:cV { LH#1:n } \BODY
  \cs_if_free:cTF { LH#1 }
   {
    \cs_gset_eq:cc { LH#1 }{ LH#1:n }
   }
   {
    \msg_error:nnn { maestroglanz/LH } { already-defined } { #1 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_set_protected:Nn { cV }
\msg_new:nnnn { maestroglanz/LH } { already-defined }
 {
  LH#1~already~defined
 }
 {
  You~used~\token_to_str:N \begin{LHZZ}{#1}~before
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{LHZZ}{XY}
write stuff here 

refer to #1
\end{LHZZ}

\LHXY{parameter}

\begin{LHZZ}{XY}a\end{LHZZ}

\end{document}
```

Without the error check, the code part would look like

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{LHZZ}[1]
 {
  \cs_set_protected:cV { LH#1:n } \BODY
  \cs_gset_eq:cc { LH#1 }{ LH#1:n }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_set_protected:Nn { cV }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

### Update

With `xparse` released 2019-05-03 the code can become

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{LHZZ}{m +b}
 {
  \cs_set_protected:cn { LH#1:n } { #2 }
  \cs_if_free:cTF { LH#1 }
   {
    \cs_gset_eq:cc { LH#1 }{ LH#1:n }
   }
   {
    \msg_error:nnn { maestroglanz/LH } { already-defined } { #1 }
   }
 }{}
\msg_new:nnnn { maestroglanz/LH } { already-defined }
 {
  LH#1~already~defined
 }
 {
  You~used~\token_to_str:N \begin{LHZZ}{#1}~before
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{LHZZ}{XY}
write stuff here 

refer to #1
\end{LHZZ}

\LHXY{parameter}

\begin{LHZZ}{XY}a\end{LHZZ}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain briefly (if this is possible) when to use `\cs_set_protected` in a way which doesn't assume an understanding of the corresponding TeX macros? If this query asks something unmanageably big, please just ignore it. I don't know enough to have a sense of whether the question is a reasonable one or not.

Comment: @cfr Basically, you always use `_protected`, unless you have good reasons not to; the good reason is that you want the function is expandable in `x` arguments. For instance, the analog of `\thesection` should not be protected.

Comment: @cfr Yes, but it wasn't right. Your impression about `\NewDocumentCommand` is wrong as well.

Comment: OK. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't (that) crazy.

Comment: So I just went through one file adding `protected`s and things still seem to work, which I guess means they should be `protected`s. But I'm wary of changing the last 3 cases because the first has a note saying that you gave me the code and the other 2 are modelled on the first: `% includegraphics bit courtesy of egreg (chat 2015-01-08)
\cs_new:Npn \cfr_includegraphics:nn #1 #2
 {
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
 }
`. I don't know if you can tell from this why this shouldn't be protected?

Comment: Hello again, I like the second one best, because, it uses only the environ-package and nothing else. I prefer code I understand (most). I dont get yet, what the `\noexpand`, `\expandafter` and `\unexpanded` does. Though I googled it a lot. I added the new MWE in an edit.
I did a MWE for the more final version. But it throws an error. I suppose, that it has to do with the expand-things.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your minimal example turned into a working one:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter

\@ifdefinable\@my@temporary{} % check availability of the name
% That's my environment:
\NewEnviron{LHZZ}[1]{%
    \let \newcommand \relax
    \protected@xdef\@my@temporary{%
        \newcommand{\csname LH#1\endcsname}[1]{\BODY}}%
    \aftergroup\@my@temporary
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

% That's the use of it:  
\begin{LHZZ}{XY}
    write stuff here 

    refer to ##1 % sorry, doubling "#" is necessary here
\end{LHZZ}

\LHXY{parameter} %the command \LHXY has been created indirectly by \begin{LHZZ}

\end{document}
```

---

**Edit:** I think using `\newcommand` instead of `\global\edef` (see Christian’s answer; note, however, that `\global\edef` is exactly the same as `\xdef`) does have some added value, because one retains, for example, the ability to define a default argument:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter

\@ifdefinable\@my@temporary@x{} % check availability of the names
\@ifdefinable\@my@temporary@y{}
% That's my environment:
\NewEnviron{LHZZ}[1]{%
    \let \newcommand \relax
    \protected@xdef\@my@temporary@x{%
        \newcommand{\csname LH#1\endcsname}[1]{\BODY}
    }%
    % ... but this one works too (the astersik is there only to illustrate 
    % another possibility: define a non-"\long" command):
    \protected@xdef\@my@temporary@y{%
        \newcommand*{\csname MG#1\endcsname}[1][default]{\BODY}
    }%
    \aftergroup\@my@temporary@x
    \aftergroup\@my@temporary@y
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

% That's the use of it:  
\begin{LHZZ}{XY}
    write stuff here 
    refer to ##1\par % sorry, doubling "#" is necessary here
\end{LHZZ}

Text before.

\LHXY{parameter} %the command \LHXY has been created indirectly by \begin{LHZZ}
\MGXY[parameter]
\MGXY

Text after.

\end{document}
```

---

**Edit 2:** Always double-check that the brain is connected before writing to TeX.SX!  (Will it be, now?)  Here is a cleaner implementation of the same basic idea:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter

\@ifdefinable\@my@temporary@x{} % check availability of the names
\@ifdefinable\@my@temporary@y{}
% That's my environment:
\NewEnviron{LHZZ}[1]{%
    \xdef\@my@temporary@x{%
        \noexpand\newcommand{\csname LH#1\endcsname}[1]{%
            \unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}%
        }%
    }%
    % ... but this one works too (the astersik is there only to illustrate 
    % another possibility: define a non-"\long" command):
    \xdef\@my@temporary@y{%
        \noexpand\newcommand*{\csname MG#1\endcsname}[1][default]{%
            \unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}%
        }%
    }%
    \aftergroup\@my@temporary@x
    \aftergroup\@my@temporary@y
    % Obviously, in a real application you'd choose only one of the two 
    % possibiities.
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

\begingroup % to show that normal scoping is obeyed

% That's the use of it:  
\begin{LHZZ}{XY}
    write stuff here 
    refer to \texttt{#1}\par % doubling the "#" is no longer necessary
\end{LHZZ}

Now \verb|\LHXY| is
\begin{flushleft}
    \ttfamily \meaning\LHXY
\end{flushleft}

Text before.

\LHXY{parameter} %the command \LHXY has been created indirectly by \begin{LHZZ}
\MGXY[parameter]
\MGXY

Text after.

\endgroup

Here \verb|\LHXY| is \textbf{%
    \ifdefined \LHXY defined\else not defined\fi
}.

\end{document}
```

But I’d better follow @egreg’s solicitation… (see  comments ;-)

Comment: No `##1` is actually necessary; more important, you should use `\protected@xdef`, not `\xdef`.

Comment: @egreg: `\protected@xdef`, yes, of course!  Thanks for noticing.  But concerning the `##`, if I try with a single `#`, it doesn’t work.

Comment: You have to work harder, for that. `;-)`

Comment: Don't you like the expl3 version?

Comment: @egreg: I logged in again for the sole purpose of upvoting it (I also like the LaTeX2e version, however).  But are you soliciting an upvote? ;-)

Comment: No, I was soliciting you to learn `expl3`. ;-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Am I right? You instantiate a macro with `\xdef` and with `\aftergroup` it is expanded after the expansion of `\begin(...)` and `\end(...)`. But is it expanded at the point of definition or at the call of `\aftergroup`? I would say aftergroup, but I m not sure.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: `\csname LH#1\endcsname` (resp., `\csname MG#1\endcsname`) and `\BODY` are expanded (the latter only by one level) when the temporary macros are defined.  For example, if `#1` is, say, `XY`, the macro `\@my@temporary@y` will be (globally) defined as `\newcommand*\MGXY[1][default]{<first-level expansion of \BODY>}`.  This temporary macro will be executed when the `LHZZ` environment is over (`\aftergroup`), so that the `\MGXY` command will be defined in the right scope.  Try inserting `\show\@my@temporary@x` and/or `\show\@my@temporary@y` before the two `\aftergroup`s.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is code golfing however...

`\expandafter\newcommand\csname ....\endcsname{...` won't work outside -- it's a local definition.

\global\expandafter\newcommand...`won't work neither due to expansion, but \global\expandafter\def\csname...` would work, but since the environment body shall be grabbed, the `\BODY` macro must be expanded first, otherwise it would be undefined outside of the environment, so either use `\expandafter\xdef\csname....` or `\global\expandafter\edef\csname...`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{environ}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\NewEnviron{LHZZ}[1]{%
  \long\global\expandafter\edef\csname LH#1\endcsname##1{\BODY\ ##1}
}

\begin{LHZZ}{XY}
  write stuff here 

  Other stuff here
\end{LHZZ}


\begin{document}


\LHXY{parameter} %the command \LHXY has been created indirectly by \begin{LHZZ}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I hadn’t seen this answer before posting mine (I did not refresh the page).

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: No worries, you provided a different answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `environ` package then you can write something like this:

```
\NewEnviron{LHZZ}[1]{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname LH#1\expandafter\endcsname
       \expandafter##\expandafter1\expandafter{\BODY}}
```

Note, that the code is much more compact than the usage of eTeX's `\unexpanded`, four hashes, etc...